# Изменение <details> </details>

Tags: html, css3

```css
summary {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

summary::before {
  content: '\2771';
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

details[open]>summary::before {
  content: '\2716';
}
```

```html
<p>text text text text
  <details>
    <summary>open</summary>
    text text text text text text
  </details>
</p>
```

Как сделать чтоб **OPEN** был в низу текста, а после открытия была надпись **CLOSE**,  чтоб при нажатии кнопки *открыть*, кнопка находилась всегда  снизу, а после открытия, текст изменялся на *закрыть*?

Comment: Лучше уж самому написать, чем мучиться с `details`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так

```css
summary
{
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(0em + 5px);
}

summary::before
{
  content: '\2771   Open';
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(-2.3em);
}

details[open] > summary::before
{
  content: '\2716   Close';
}
```

```html
 <p>text text text text text text</p>
<details>
  <summary></summary>
  <span>text text text text text text</span>
</details>
```

Comment: Ну костыль же откровенный. Стоит написать `text<br/>text` и всё ломается к чертям

Comment: Тут вообще трудно без костылей подобное сделать. Куда проще написать пару строк на js и всё будет нормально работать... Да, костыль. Полностью согласен, но тут ещё и от задачи зависит применение